# Does realm database support blazor web assembly?

Tags: c#, realm, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mongodb-realm

I have an ambitious goal to build a cross platform app that would share as much code as possible that would run on desktop, mobile devices and web browsers. The application is going to use [realm database](https://www.mongodb.com/realm) with mongoDB atlas for cloud sync.

All of those nice offline-first, automatic sync capabilities are available for desktop and mobile devices. I wonder if I’d be able to use the same for blazor web assembly?

Let’s say it’s not possible, what alternative could I use as database? And what could I do to implement real time sync with mongoDB realm cloud database on blazor as a fallback?

Comment: They support Angular and the like, so a wrapper should be possible. But Google shows no matches, you'll probably have to start one yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the Realm Database, nor Realm Sync can run in the browser at the moment. The team has plans to explore Wasm as a potential target, but there's no definitive timeline for that yet.

In terms of workarounds, you could use [GraphQL](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/graphql/) or the [Web SDK](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/mongodb/) both of which expose an API to query MongoDB via an HTTP API. One edge the Web SDK has over GraphQL is that it supports watching a collection for changes, whereas GraphQL only has Query and Mutation support. With both of these solutions, you'll need to design your own caching/storage layer.

Comment: Nikola thanks a lot for the answer, all does make sense. Web SDK is javascript/typescript based. Is there another SDK that's consumable by .NET and is able to do CRUD and monitor for changes? Or I will have to create a bridge within blazor to access js sdks?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's one at this point, so bridging the JS SDK seems like your best bet.

Comment: Got you. This may be a different thing, I came across this page. It seems there is C# SDK to monitor collection changes, not sure if it's intended to use in every place where .net works or has limitations on target platforms

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: These docs are for the C# driver - that one's different from the Realm SDK. Technically, you can use the C# driver, unfortunately, only a subset of the wire protocol functionality is exposed on MongoDB Realm: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/connect-over-the-wire-protocol/ and change streams is not part of that list. So while I haven't tested it personally, I don't believe it will work for your use case.

Comment: Make sense Nikola! Thanks again for clarifications.